# Changing HDMI diplay from 1 to 2 programmatically

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, kotlin

I have a Raspberry PI 4 with a dual display setup I wanted to show different operations on both displays depending on some logic.

My application is built with compose multiplatform I can make two screens by just following the code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = application {

    Window(
        onCloseRequest = app::onDestroy, title = " WINDOW 1 ", state = rememberWindowState(
            placement = WindowPlacement.Fullscreen
        )
    ) {
        App(app)
    }

   Window(
        onCloseRequest = app::onDestroy, title = " WINDOW 2 ", state = rememberWindowState(
            placement = WindowPlacement.Fullscreen
        )
    ) {
        App(app)
    }

}
```

But I want to set WINDOW 1 to HDMI 1 and WINDOW 2 to HDMI 2 programmatically any idea how can I do that ?